# Dynamic script to Drop Indices of a specific column

Tags: sql-server, database-design, index, migration

I´m currently writing an SQL script to update our database and for that I need a script to drop indices that rely on a specific column (because I also want to drop the column).

In my script I have used the normal approach by using the following SQL for *known* indices (before dropping the column via ALTER TABLE).

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = '{IndexName}' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('{TableName}'))
BEGIN
    DROP INDEX {Table}.{Index};
END
```

But on some systems of our software I cannot use this approach, because there are some indices that are added manually and I need to identify these indices to drop them also.

I have found a good SQL statement on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/765892/83039) to list all indices, columns and tables, but I´m stuck how I can select the names of the indices so that I can pass them to DROP INDEX.

Pseudo-code (something like that):

```
 declare indiciesToDrop = Select indexName from sql-statement where t.Name = {TableName} and col.Name = {ColumnName};

 DROP INDEX indiciesToDrop;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are planning to `DROP` a column and the indices that support it, I'll assume that doing so is a product of well-thought plan.  Also, I'll assume that you want to drop ANY indice that use the to-be-deleted column, regardless of how it is used.   If so, you can build your script based upon something like below.  You can put this in a stored procedure and pass the parameters, TableName, ColumnName, and SchemaName in this example.

Now, before you run this or any modified version of it, please be clear that once this script starts, all associated indices plus the column will be dropped, and such decision shouldn't be taken lightly.

I'm assuming you have already done your homework, but please allow me.  One situation that might become a problem is when the column you want to drop (C) is a part of a multi-column index that supports a popular query.  For example, let's consider the following structure.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nci_tableA_ABC ON dbo.A(A,B,C) INCLUDE (D,E);

SELECT D,E FROM dbo.A WHERE A=@? AND B=@? AND C=@?
```

If this query is very frequently used hence the index is frequently used, dropping this index will severely impact the performance, and the index needs to be manually recreated albeit without the column C.  I'm sure there are other risks to consider.

Also please note that this script is completely void of error trapping or constraint checking.  If the column you are interested has constraint(s), that need to be dropped before the column can be dropped. You can use `sys.objects` table to construct dynamic SQL.  (and this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818837/how-to-check-if-default-value-constraint-exist-not-exist)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Tempdb..#IndexList', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #IndexList;
GO
DECLARE 
    @SchemaName SYSNAME,
    @DropThisIndex SYSNAME,
    @DropThisColumn SYSNAME,
    @CheckThisTable SYSNAME,
    @LoopCounter INT,
    @IndexCount INT,
    @DropColumnSQL NVARCHAR(1000);

SET @SchemaName = N'SchemaName'
SET @CheckThisTable = @SchemaName + '.' + N'TableName';
SET @DropThisColumn = N'ColumnName';
SET @LoopCounter = 1;
SET @DropColumnSQL = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @CheckThisTable + ' DROP COLUMN ' + @DropThisColumn

--First check if the column even exists--

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns 
            WHERE Name = @DropThisColumn AND Object_ID = Object_ID(@CheckThisTable))

    BEGIN --the column exists in the specified table Construct a temporary table that stores name of index to be dropped--
        SELECT 
            I.name AS IndexName
        INTO #IndexList
        FROM 
            sys.index_columns IC 
            INNER JOIN 
            sys.objects O
        ON  IC.[object_id]= O.[Object_ID]
            INNER JOIN
            sys.indexes I
        ON  IC.[object_id] = I.[object_id] AND
            IC.index_id = I.index_id
            INNER JOIN 
            sys.columns C 
        ON  IC.[object_id] = C.[object_id] AND
            IC.column_id = C.column_id
        WHERE O.[type] NOT IN ('S','IT') AND --we don't want anything to do with System or Internal Table
            IC.[INDEX_ID] <> 1 AND --neither Clustered Index
            IC.[object_id] = OBJECT_id(@CheckThisTable,'U') AND
            C.name = @DropThisColumn;

        --Check how many times to loop through--
        SET @IndexCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
        PRINT CAST(@IndexCount AS NVARCHAR) + N' index(es) on the table [' + @CheckThisTable + N'] for the column [' +  @DropThisColumn + '] found'

        IF @IndexCount > 0 --there is at least one index(es) that are associated with the table and the column in question.  Begin loop--
            BEGIN
                WHILE @LoopCounter < @IndexCount+1
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT TOP(@LoopCounter) 
                            @DropThisIndex = IndexName
                        FROM #IndexList;
                        --Execute Drop Index statement--
                        PRINT N'Loop ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@LoopCounter) + N': Dropping [' + @DropThisIndex + ']'
                        EXEC('DROP INDEX ' + @DropthisIndex + ' ON ' + @CheckThisTable);
                        SET @LoopCounter +=1;
                    END;
                --Dropping Index is done. Let's drop the column now
                PRINT N'Dropping the column [' + @DropThiscolumn + ']'  
                EXEC(@DropColumnSQL);
            END;             
        ELSE --There was no index.  let's just drop the column.
            BEGIN
                PRINT N'Dropping the column [' + @DropThiscolumn + ']'    
                EXEC(@DropColumnSQL);
            END
    END
ELSE --no column found in the specified table.  Are the input corrects?  
    PRINT 'The column [' + @DropThisColumn + '] in the table [' + @CheckThisTable + '] wasn''t found' 
;
```

Now, if your goal is to drop *ONLY* the indices that has the to-be-dropped column as the key (left most key that is), then you can modify `#IndexList`  table like below and filter unwanted row, like Clustered Index, before your get the loop count.

```
CREATE TABLE #IndexList
    (IndexName SYSNAME,
    IndexType NVARCHAR(255),
    Index_Key SYSNAME)

INSERT INTO #indexlist
EXEC sys.sp_helpindex N'TableName';
```

Comment: I will check your script and be sure that I know what I am doing. Since I cannot change or edit existing indicies I have to drop and recreate them. Most of the `custom` indices are part of trial and error and not part of our default indices. I have full control of the systems and database backups to perform my change.

Answer (score 1):

One would hope that the indexes were created for a good reason.  Assuming these indexes have (or at least had) a good reason to exist, writing a script to blow them away without understanding why they were created or having a plan to replace them seems like a bad idea. Most indexes are created on more than one column. If a column is dropped the index should be updated and recreated without the dropped column. In the case of an index that contains just the dropped column, yes, it can be safely dropped. However, dropping the indexes without manual investigation is likely to lead to more problems.

Potentially a better solution might be to write a script that would check for the existence of manually created indexes and report them.  Manual investigation and analysis seems like the most prudent approach here.

Comment: You have missed this important point: `because I also want to drop the column`.

Comment: I didn't miss that point.  As I stated in my answer, the indexes were created for a reason.  There was an underlying problem that the developers were attempting to solve/fix by creating the index.  By dropping the index you are going to be bringing that problem back.  This should not be done without manual investigation and analysis.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your argument. The OP needs to drop a column, so what would be the point in keeping the indices on that column when the column's gone (assuming for the moment that it would be at all possible technically), even if they were created for a reason?

Comment: Because most indexes are created on more than one column.  If a column is dropped the index should be updated and recreated without the dropped column.  In the case of an index that contains just the dropped column, yes, it can be safely dropped.  However, dropping the indexes without manual investigation is likely to lead to more problems. Hence, my answer.

Comment: Makes sense. Do you think you could incorporate that elaboration into your answer? I mean, your post's starting with a half-allegation that the OP may be asking their question out of annoyance *can* give one the impression that you may have missed the point I mentioned in my first comment. It's quite possible, though, that it was only me and, perhaps, whoever upvoted my comment that thought you have indeed missed it, in which case your answer is probably fine as it is.